# Android Studio Token Based authentication - Date based

Tags: java, android

So I'm tasked with a challenge to only allow users through to the next activity if their valid licenses are not past its expiry date if its past that date then to reject the user and display an error message

This is to be done using a token-based authentication, something I'm only just getting into, does anyone know how or where to read things about this?

Comment: Are you getting the token from the server or do you want to generate it?

Comment: I want to Generate it

Comment: Well, Tokens are generated from the server end by using and server-side programming language such as PHP, JSP, ASP. etc.. In Android you can use the token to authenticate and you can use the expiry date to check whether the token is expired or not.. depending on the date we can reject the user and display an error message.